# Journey Builder Entry Setting

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I got a funny scenario, where this hasn't happen to me in the past/previous version of Journey Builder and wanted to ask for your opinion or possible solution.

- I have an Entry DE that is populated from SQL Query activity with
  Update method.
- The journey entry settings is configured as Re-entry after exit.
- The journey is run using an automation studio schedule.
- The above method, creates the Inject Audience tile in the automation 
  schedule as the last step in the automation.
- The journey record evaluation is to evaluate all records.

Although there is only 1 record in the Entry DE but it seems like JB keeps injecting the same contact every time the automation is run.

Have I configured the above correctly?

Thank you guys in advance.

Yoppy

Comment: what activities are in the journey? How long does it take for a record to complete the journey? Is it possible that the record finishes the journey and is therefore eligible for re-entry each time the automation is run? Are you wanting it to evaluate new records only?

Comment: Thanks @TravisNaughton. the activities are wait, check contact email if not null, send email (else exit if email is null) and wait before exit.  we plan to expand the journey down the track. The journey length is only 2 mins so it is therefore eligible to enter as soon as they exit.  should I only set this only to evaluate new records?  The entry DE is a combined PK of subskey + opportunityid from sales cloud.  Thank you again in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the setup of your journey the records are exiting the journey before the automation is run, meaning they are eligible for entry each time the automation runs.

If the automation is set to evaluate new records it will always inject the contact once they have exited the journey no matter how long it might be in the future. This is ok if its the intended functionality.

If you want to limit the records from being injected incorrectly you could configure it a few ways.

1. You could set the entry criteria automation to evaluate new records only. In your case you might want to consider how the same person could be 2 different records based on your PK and how that might work with re-entry based only on subscriber key. What criteria would make a record eligible for re-entry.
2. Have an update record activity in the journey to flag the injected record as having been processed. Then in your data filter or query exclude records that have the processed flag from entry.
3. Depending on how long the journey will be and how often you would want a record to be eligible for re-entry you could set a data retention policy on the data extension to remove records after a certain period of time.

Comment: Thank you @ TravisNaughton. This gives me an idea moving forward. Thanks again!